# Debugging invalid moves in a 15 puzzle

Tags: javascript, debugging, if-statement, logic, logical-operators

I made a little [15 puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle) which I want to be shuffled in the beginning. I start from the completed state and do 1000 random "fakeClicks" on tiles of which some are valid according to my code and most are not. The valid "fakeClicks" cause the `emptyTile` and the `selectedTile` to swap their positions by swaping their `top` and `left` values.

Everything (except the `checkCompleteness()` method which does not exist yet) **seems to work - until one actually tries to solve the puzzle**. With a small n, I reached the [unsolvable game situation](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:15-puzzle-loyd.svg#/media/File:15-puzzle-loyd.svg) more than 50 percent of the time.

How is this possible when during shuffling I do valid moves only? Obviously it must be something about my code checking if a move is valid or not:

```
if ((Math.abs(selectedX - emptyX) === tileSize) ^ (Math.abs(selectedY - emptyY) === tileSize)) {
```

(The ^ (xor) is to prevent diagonal moves.)

Does anyone see where the problem is to be found? Or does anyone have a suggestion for a good debugging strategy? After more than an hour of debugging, I am kind of clueless.

```js
var idList = ["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "t6", "t7", "t8", "t9", "t10", "t11", "t12", "t13", "t14", "t15", "t0"];
var tileSize = 100;

var init = function() {
    // place tiles on the board and add listener
    for (var column = 0; column < 4; column++) {
        for (var row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
            var div = document.querySelector("." + idList[row * 4 + column]);
            div.style.top = row * tileSize + "px";
            div.style.left = column * tileSize + "px";
            if (idList[row * 4 + column] !== "t0") {
                div.addEventListener("click", clickListener);
            }
        }
    }
    // shuffle tiles
    for (i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        var fakeClick = parseInt(Math.random() * 15);
        swapTiles(idList[fakeClick]);
    }
};

var clickListener = function(e) {
    var selectedTileClass = e.target.classList[1];
    swapTiles(selectedTileClass);
    //checkCompleteness(); // to be done later
};

var swapTiles = function(selectedTileClass) {
    // get empty tile and selected tile
    var selectedTile = document.querySelector("." + selectedTileClass);
    var selectedX = parseInt(selectedTile.style.left);
    var selectedY = parseInt(selectedTile.style.top);
    var emptyTile = document.querySelector(".t0");
    var emptyX = parseInt(emptyTile.style.left);
    var emptyY = parseInt(emptyTile.style.top);
    // only swap tiles  if selected tile "next to" empty tile
    if ((Math.abs(selectedX - emptyX) === tileSize) ^ (Math.abs(selectedY - emptyY) === tileSize)) {
        selectedTile.style.left = emptyX + "px";
        selectedTile.style.top = emptyY + "px";
        emptyTile.style.left = selectedX + "px";
        emptyTile.style.top = selectedY + "px";
    }
};
```

```css
.board {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: firebrick;
    border: 2px firebrick solid;
}

.tile {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px firebrick solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: orange;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: firebrick;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .25s linear;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.t0 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    margin: 2px;
    border: 2px orange solid;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: all .25s linear;
}
```

```html
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body onload="init();">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="center">
            <div class="board">
                <div class="tile t1">1</div>
                <div class="tile t2">2</div>
                <div class="tile t3">3</div>
                <div class="tile t4">4</div>
                <div class="tile t5">5</div>
                <div class="tile t6">6</div>
                <div class="tile t7">7</div>
                <div class="tile t8">8</div>
                <div class="tile t9">9</div>
                <div class="tile t10">10</div>
                <div class="tile t11">11</div>
                <div class="tile t12">12</div>
                <div class="tile t13">13</div>
                <div class="tile t14">14</div>
                <div class="tile t15">15</div>
                <div class="t0"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, your test is wrong.

Imagine a small board with the selected tile in the center

```
ooooo
ooooo
ooxoo
ooooo
ooooo
```

and now look at what the two truth tables of the 2 predicates give depending on where the empty tile is.

```
ftftf
ftftf
ftxtf
ftftf
ftftf
```

and

```
fffff
ttttt
ffxff
ttttt
fffff
```

mix them with an xor and you get

```
ftftf
tftft
ftxtf
tftft
ftftf
```

which means you get the correct response  on the "first circle" around the tile, but you get incorrect responses farther from the tile.

Comment: So I have to check each predicate for being on the same row/column a x.

Comment: That makes: `if (((Math.abs(selectedX - emptyX) === tileSize) && selectedY === emptyY) ^ ((Math.abs(selectedY - emptyY) === tileSize) && selectedX === emptyX))`

Comment: yes it should work like that. you can replace the ^ by a regular or || because xor is not necessary in this formula if you look at the truth tables.